# Change value in array key that has a specific sub key value in php

Tags: php, arrays

What is the shortest way to change multiple values in array key that has a specific value in it?

For example, I have this array:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["state"]=>
    string(6) "active"
    ["payer_mail"]=>
    string(12) "mail@none.com"
    ["start"]=>
    string(12) "06/05/2015"
    ["end"]=>
    string(8) "08/07/2017"
    ["price"]=>
    string(8) "45.00"
    ["keystring"]=>
    string(8) "493457025"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["place"]=>
    string(2) "47"
    ["state"]=>
    string(8) "canceled"
    ["payer_mail"]=>
    string(12) "mail@none.com"
    ["start"]=>
    string(9) "20/8/2014"
    ["end"]=>
    string(10) "20/10/2017"
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "95.00"
    ["keystring"]=>
    string(8) "34879205"
  }
}
```

And I want to change the `"state"` value of the key that has `"34879205"` value for his `"keystring"` sub-key.

Comment: use `foreach()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way i found is:

```
$key = array_search('34879205', array_column($array, 'keystring'));
$array[$key]['state'] = 'newvalue';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foreach()`:-

```
foreach($array as &$value) {
    if ($value['keystring'] == '34879205'){
        $value['state'] = "";//change value here
    }
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/838789

Comment: Thanks. but i think i found a little more "php style" answer. what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_map function

```
$result = array_map(function ($element) {
    if ($element['keystring'] === '34879205') {
        $element['state'] = 'new_state';
    }

    return $element;
}, $array);
```

Comment: `array_map()` mostly used when you want to apply some custom logic (function) on each array element. So for this sort of question it's a burden to do that. But answer is correct, no issue is there.

Comment: Thanks! but i think the other solutions are more elegant.